# How to find eigenvalues of this 3x3 Jacobian Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am having to learn how to do jacobian matrices, determinants, and finding eigenvalues on my own and I cannot seem to find reasonable eigenvalues for this jacobian matrix.
When I try to solve it I get absurdly long answers. My professor mentioned the Routh Hurwitz method but I after attempting to learn it on wikipedia and youtube It was just over my head at the level I am right now. If you could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated, an explanation is more helpful to me in the long run than just an answer, since I have to do more jacobian matrices more complicated than this one.

$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -C_+ - \mu &  0      & -\beta T_+ \\
   C_+ \beta & -\alpha &  \beta T_+ \\
   0         &  k      &   -\gamma
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Thank you in advance, I truly appreciate anyone who takes the time to try and help me.

Comment: Can you post the equation you get to determine the eigenvalues? Should be a cubic.

Comment: I tried subtracting lambda from the diagonal and then finding the determinant, and then used mathematica to try and simplify it but each eigenvalue is several lines long with multiple imaginary parts. I hope that answers what you're asking, I'm sorry if I've misunderstood you, I'm very lost as to how to do this correctly.

Comment: There should be a mathematica function that will calculate the the eigenvalues of your matrix

Comment: Eigenvalues[{-C \[Beta]-\[Mu],0,-T \[Beta]},{C \[Beta],-\[Alpha],T \[Beta]},{0,k,-\[Gamma]}]

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the function that will do it, but the syntax looks right. Except your zeroes look like the letter "o" which wouldn't compile in mathematica. And you have to declare all your parameters as constants, not including lambda.

Comment: I assure you they are 0's, I copied it directly from my mathematica notebook and if you paste it into mathematica it also converts the [Beta], [Mu], etc... into their correct symbols as well.

Comment: Just making sure; if there isn't an eigenvalue function supported in mathematica, there is most definitely a determinant function that you can feed your (lambda subtracted from diagonals) matrix to.

Comment: Okay I tried that, so you're saying that method, subtracting lambda from the diagonal and finding the determinant, is the correct way to find the eigenvalues of this matrix? I'm not sure why but I had it in my head that you had to do something different since this wasn't an identity matrix, but maybe I was just thinking about the identity matrix in [lambda*I-A]=0. If that is the correct way to solve this, you have just saved me a world of confusion!

Comment: Yes, the eigenvalues for a square matrix $A_{n\times n}$ come from solving the equation $$A_{n\times n}-\lambda I_n=0$$ Actually I'll just post it as an answer then if that's what your confusion was!

Comment: Haha that's exactly what my problem was thank you so much! And I was about to tell you to post it as an answer rather than a comment so I could give you credit for clearing it up, thank you so much @graydad !

Comment: No problem Mr. F :) Based on the thumbnail picture you have along with your username, I feel like we'd get along pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in the comments, you are interested in solving $$\det\left(\left[\begin{array}\ (-C^+\beta-\mu-\lambda)&0&-\beta T_+ \\C^+\beta&-\alpha-\lambda&\beta T_+ \\0&\kappa&-\gamma-\lambda \end{array} \right] \right)$$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the help. And I'm glad someone appreciates the Moss avatar!